# the next() method in python generator works weird

Tags: python, generator

```
def conflict(state, nextX):
    nextY = len(state)
    for i in range(nextY):
        if abs(state[i]-nextX) in (0, nextY-i):
            return True
    return False

def queens(num=8, state=()):
    for pos in range(num):
        if not conflict(state, pos):
            if len(state) == num-1:
                yield (pos,)
            else:
                results=queens(num, state + (pos,))
                for res in results:
                    yield (pos,) + res 

print list(queens(8))
```

It‘s a solution of the eight queens,which works well.But when i did a little change.it’s becoming weird all about the next() method in python Generator.

```
def conflict(state, nextX):
    nextY = len(state)
    for i in range(nextY):
        if abs(state[i]-nextX) in (0, nextY-i):
            return True
    return False

def queens(num=8, state=()):
    for pos in range(num):
        if not conflict(state, pos):
            if len(state) == num-1:
                yield (pos,)
            else:
                results=queens(num, state + (pos,))
                for res in results:
                    yield (pos,) +results.next()   //here is the change. res -->results.next()  

print list(queens(8))
```

It's just print a [ ]. How embarrassed i am! I can't understand why the next() method works in any other situations but not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What were you expecting to happen?

When you call `next` on a generator, it advances the generator and returns the next item.  Your base case (`len(state) == num-1`) only yields a single item, so in that case it will advance the iterator, receive `StopIteration`, and terminate the loop, so you won't get any results back.

The root problem is that you're trying to advance an iterator while looping over it; that's unlikely to work well.

Comment: But why there is no traceback down there just like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.py", line 6, in <module>
    a.next()
StopIteration

Comment: @unkonwn_kid the `StopIteration` is caught by the `for res in results` loop, or ultimately by the `list` constructor.

Comment: Why can it automatically catch the exception?So why  Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.py", line 6, in <module> a.next() StopIteration can be raised in another "for" loop

Comment: def foo():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i

a=foo()

for res in a:
    print res
    print a.next()


But why this has a traceback with 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print a.next()
StopIteration

Comment: Because it's not being caught by a `for` loop or by a `list` (etc.) constructor.  `StopIteration` is only caught by a `for` loop when it's thrown within the `in` expression.